# Object reference cannot fix

Tags: c#

> Error CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'Blip.Sprite' HeliBoatMissions

```
namespace heliBoatMissions
{ }  
    public class Radar

{
    void Marker()

{
        new Blip(new Vector3(-699.4645f, -1448.289f, 5.000523f),

Blip.Sprite = BlipSprite.Helicopter);
}

}
```

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I Think this is your issue

```
namespace heliBoatMissions
{ }
```

Change it to this

```
namespace heliBoatMissions
{
```

UPDATE

Also I noticed that you do not assign this

```
new Blip(new Vector3(-699.4645f, -1448.289f, 5.000523f),
```

to a variable. Nor do you end it with a semicolon.

I think something like this might be what you're after?

```
namespace heliBoatMissions
{
    public class Radar
    {
        public object BlipSprite { get; private set; }

        void Marker()
        {
            var v = new Blip(new Vector3(-699.4645f, -1448.289f, 5.000523f));
            v.Sprite = BlipSprite.Helicopter;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and NOT telling me to go read a c# tutorial. I did that and the error is still there.  It seems to be a problem with the: 'Blip.Sprite' part.

Comment: You are correct, updating my answer

Comment: Thank you for not being a keyboard warrior and presuming that I have not read tutorials when I already have. I have learnt more by making mistakes and fixing them, mostly without any help then when I read tutorials only. That has fixed my issue, hope your day is a good one :)